# generating a string representation of a list of tuples

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples of form

```
[("very", "ADJ"), ("slow", "ADJ"), ("programmer", "NOUN")]
```

My desired output is a single string of form:

```
"very/ADJ slow/ADJ programmer/NOUN"
```

This being python, I know I can do this in a one-liner using the `format()` and `join()` methods, but I can't get the syntax quite right. My most recent attempt was:

```
output_string = " ".join(["{0}/{1}".format(x) for x in list_of_tuples])
```

which threw an `Index Error: tuple index out of range"`

Comment: All you need is a `*`.

Comment: `"{0}/{1}".format(*x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `format(*x)` so that the `x` tuple is expanded into arguments. Otherwise you are trying to call `format` with a single argument which is itself a tuple.

That said, if you know that these are all 2-tuples, I'd just go with the simpler:

```
output_string = " ".join(a + "/" + b for a, b in list_of_tuples)
```

Also note that there's no need to use a list comprehension to pass into `join` -- just use a [generator comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) instead.

Comment: Thanks - problem was solved in comments, but will accept your answer when I can for explaining why this solved it.

Answer (score 1):

```
words = [("very", "ADJ"), ("slow", "ADJ"), ("programmer", "NOUN")]
' '.join('/'.join((x,y)) for x,y in words)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` too:

```
>>> ' '.join(map(lambda t: '{}/{}'.format(*t), li))
'very/ADJ slow/ADJ programmer/NOUN'
```

And, that same method without the `lambda`:

```
>>> ' '.join(map('/'.join, li))
'very/ADJ slow/ADJ programmer/NOUN'
```

Which works even if you have more than two elements in your tuples.